# No audio input and non-existing S/PDIF sinks/sources in list

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, alsa

I've installed a simple utility for audio recording Sound Recorder, but it won't start recording, as there is only one source: "Master".

I use Behringer UMC202 USB audio interface; it has one stereo input and one stereo output (both analog). Audio driver is `snd_usb_audio`.

However, when I open "Sound Settings", I see two outputs: First is S/PDIF, and second is analog. Same thing with inputs, one digital and second is analog. The difference is that it does not even meter my input.

If I open `alsamixer` tool, and select my audio card with <kbd>F6</kbd> key, I see only two outputs. Real output volume may be changed by both of them.

I think that something is messed up with my configuration, causing input not to work and fake "S/PDIF" digital interfaces to be detected by Ubuntu.

I am sure that my analog input is muted, but usable. question is, how do I fix sinks/sources detection to remove digital ports and unmute my input?

What should I change in my system?

```
$ cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.13.0-24-generic.
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf9ff8000 irq 44
 1 [U96k           ]: USB-Audio - UMC202 96k
                      BEHRINGER UMC202 96k at usb-0000:00:1d.7-1, high speed
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0- 2]: digital audio capture
  3: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  5: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  6: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  7: [ 0]   : control
  8: [ 1- 0]: digital audio playback
  9: [ 1- 0]: digital audio capture
 10: [ 1]   : control
 33:        : timer
00-00: HDA Codec 0
00-00: ALC1200 Analog : ALC1200 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-01: ALC1200 Digital : ALC1200 Digital : playback 1
00-02: ALC1200 Alt Analog : ALC1200 Alt Analog : capture 1
01-00: USB Audio : USB Audio : playback 1 : capture 1
Client info
  cur  clients : 2
  peak clients : 2
  max  clients : 192

Client   0 : "System" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Timer" (Rwe-)
  Port   1 : "Announce" (R-e-)
Client  14 : "Midi Through" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Midi Through Port-0" (RWe-)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the reason is the "recording" feature is not "enabled":

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
gnome-alsamixer
```

In a dialog window find your sources and check **Rec.** for each. Input will then appear.